# Find all positive integers s.t. $10^m-8^n=2m^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all pairs of positive integers $(m,n)$ such that $10^m-8^n=2m^2$

Comment: Any ideas about how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$${10}^m - 8^n = {2^m}{5^m} - {2^{3n}}$$

so that

$$m^2 = {2^{m-1}}{5^m} - {2^{3n-1}}.$$

In particular:

$${2^{m-1}}{5^m} - {2^{3n-1}} \geq 1,$$

and

$${2^{m-1}}\left({5^m} - {2^{3n-m}}\right)$$

is a square, which means $m \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Suppose that $m > 1$.  Then the RHS of

$$m^2 = {2^{m-1}}\left({5^m} - {2^{3n-m}}\right)$$

is even while the LHS is odd (since $5^m - {2^{3n-m}}$ is always odd, unless $m = 3n$ [I'll deal with this case later]).  A contradiction.  Therefore, $m = 1$.

Substituting $m = 1$:

$$10 - {8^n} = 2$$

which gives $n = 1$.

Update:  If $m = 3n$, then

$$m^2 = {3^2}{n^2} = 2^{3n - 1}\left(5^{3n} - 1\right).$$

Since $\gcd(3,2) = 1$, then it follows that

$$2^{3n - 1} \mid n^2$$

which implies that $2^{3n - 1} \leq n^2$, contradicting $n^2 < 2^{3n - 1}$.

Therefore, in general, $m = 3n$ cannot occur.

Hence the only solution to the original problem is $(m, n) = (1, 1)$.

Comment: I don't understand '' $m^2 = {2^{m-1}}\left({5^m} - {2^{3n-m}}\right)$ is even while the LHS is odd (since $5^m−2^{3n−m}$ is always odd, unless $m=3n$ . A contradiction '' ????

Comment: @PhiLinh, the quantity $m^2 = 2^{m-1}\left(5^m - 2^{3n - m}\right)$ is a square.  Therefore, $m$ is odd, unless $3n = m$ (in which case $5^m - 2^{3n - m}$ is even).  But I've shown just now that $3n \neq m$ (in general).  Consequently, $5^m - 2^{3n - m}$ is always odd, and it follows that indeed $m$ is odd. (continued)

Comment: @PhiLinh, under the assumption $m > 1$, and by the equation $m^2 = {2^{m-1}}\left(5^m - 2^{3n-m}\right)$, it follows (from my previous comment) that the LHS is odd while the RHS is even.  This is a contradiction.  As $m$ is a positive integer, we are forced to conclude that $m = 1$.

Comment: No problem @PhiLinh, glad to be of assistance!  =)

Comment: sorry you, I don't understand ''which implies that $2^{3n−1}≤n^2$, contradicting $n^2<2^{3n−1}$.'' Why  $n^2<2^{3n−1}$ ??????

Comment: @PhiLinh, $n^2 < 2^{3n-1}$ because $2^{3n-1}$ grows faster than $n^2$ (i.e., exponential versus quadratic growth).  If you like my answer (and think it is correct), please consider accepting it.  =)